# Lua: Abbreviate Words

Tags: lua

I am looking for code to return an abbreviation of the input, i.e. "Federal Bureau of Investigation" should return FBI (preferably without the o), and also work for lowercast "federal bureau of investigation".  How would I go about doing that?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may work:

```
("Federal bureau of Investigation")
  :gsub("of","") -- remove "of"
  :gsub("(%w)%S+%s*","%1") -- leave first character of a word
  :upper() -- convert to uppercase
```

This returns "FBI"

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
do
   -- default list of words to exclude or reshape
   local stopwords = { }
   for w in ("a an and for of the to"):gmatch "%w+" do  stopwords[w] = ""  end
   -- abbreviating a phrase:
   function TLA( phrase, subst )
      subst = subst or stopwords
      -- first replace each word (incl. "'") by its abbreviation...
      -- (will leave spaces etc. in the string)
      phrase = phrase:gsub( "[%w']+", function( word )
         if not word:find "%U" then  return word  end -- OPTIONAL keep abbrevs
         word = word:lower()
         if subst[word] then  return subst[word]  end -- from substitution list
         return word:sub( 1, 1 ):upper( )             -- others: to first letter
      end )
      -- ...then remove all non-word characters
      return (phrase:gsub( "%W", "" ))
   end
end
```

It handles simple cases:

```
TLA "Ministry Of Information"  --> "MI"
TLA "floating-point exception" --> "FPE"
```

can deal with some special cases:

```
TLA "augmented BNF" --> "ABNF"
```

and adjusting the substitution list / putting non-empty strings in might also be useful:

```
TLA "one way or the other" --> "OWOO"
TLA( "one way or the other", {} ) --> "OWOTO"
TLA( "Ministry Of Information", { of = "of" } ) --> "MofI"

local custom_subst = {
   ["for"] = "4", to = "2", ["and"] = "", one = "1", two = "2", -- ...
}
TLA "Ministry for Fear, Uncertainity and Doubt" --> "MFUD"
TLA( "Ministry for Fear, Uncertainity and Doubt", custom_subst ) --> "M4FUD"
TLA( "Two-factor authentication", custom_subst ) --> "2FA"
```

As usual,

```
TLA( "there ain't no such thing as a free lunch", {} ) --> "TANSTAAFL"
```

and

```
TLA( "There is more than one way to do it!", {} ) --> "TIMTOWTDI"
```

– so there are lots of things that you may want to tweak in the code besides the substitution list.

Comment: Assertion failed: `assert(TLA"WINE Is Not an Emulator" == "WINE")` :-)

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, unless you use a specific dictionary, there is no perfect generic solution simply because many abbreviations don't follow consistent rules.

For example, think of BASIC = Beginner's All-Purpose Symbolic Instruction Code.

(Should be BAPSIC instead of BASIC)

So, with some limitations as noted, here's yet another possible acronym generator that seems to work for most 'normal' cases.

```
function acronym(s,ignore)
  ignore = ignore or
  {                                     --default list of words to ignore
  ['a'] = true, ['an'] = true, ['and'] = true, ['in'] = true, ['for'] = true,
  ['of'] = true, ['the'] = true, ['to'] = true, ['or'] = true,
  }

  local ans = {}
  for w in s:gmatch '[%w\']+' do
    if not ignore[w:lower()] then ans[#ans+1] = w:sub(1,1):upper() end
  end
  return table.concat(ans)
end
```

Comment: I had to modify it for working with CameCase (if present) as well, but I found this approach very useful, thanks! Only one thing out of curiosity... What the _ans_ variable name stands for in this case? 